# How to get all float values from string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I have string: *Entry, x: 0.0 y: -0.9980941 Entry, x: 1.0 y: -0.9686125 Entry, x: 2.0 y: 0.9044667*

How to get all float values via regex: **0.0, -0.9980941, 1.0, -0.9686125, 2.0, 0.9044667**

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed/

Answer (score 3):

The following is the regex from https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

> [-+]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]+

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.regex package to do that.

The regular expression \d matches digits & is equivalent to [0..9]. \d* asks to match 0 or more occurrences of the preceding expression. '.?' matches 0 or 1 occurrence of the dot. \d+ matches 1 or more of expression of the previous \d. So all together regEx searches for [0..9].[0..9] pattern in the string.

Have a look at [java_regular_expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) for knowing the differences between *, . ,? and + in regEx.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Entry, x: 0.0 y: -0.9980941 Entry, x: 1.0 y: -0.9686125 Entry, x: 2.0 y: 0.9044667";
        String regEx = "\\d*\\.?\\d+";

        Pattern patternObject = Pattern.compile(regEx);     
        Matcher matcher = patternObject.matcher(str);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());        
        }   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the `[-+]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]+` pattern suggested by @Ashish Mathew was not working for me as it is because `.` needs to be escaped.

Also, I recommend that you read the link he posted so you'll find the final working solution and the way it was built along with explanations.

This is my working code based on it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = " Entry, x: 0.0 y: -0.9980941 Entry, x: 1.0 y: -0.9686125 Entry, x: 2.0 y: 0.9044667";
    List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[-+]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*").matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        allMatches.add(m.group());
    }
    // [0.0, -0.9980941, 1.0, -0.9686125, 2.0, 0.9044667]
    System.out.println(allMatches);
}
```